# Regular expression for the log format

Tags: python, regex, string

Could anyone help me in writing a regular expression for a particular log format? Below is the sample log and the regular expression I wrote for it, but it does not work.

```
Log : 64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:05:49 -0800] "GET
/twiki/bin/edit/Main/Double_bounce_sender?topicparent=Main.ConfigurationVariables
HTTP/1.1" 401 12846
```

Regular Expression I tried was: `"%h - - %t \"%r\" %>s %b"`

Comment: Could you please specify what exactly you want to match in this string?

Comment: Could you be more specific than *"it does not work"*? How are you applying the regular expression, what is the output, and what did you expect instead?

Answer (score 0):

Each log is probably stored in separate line. Try simple:

```
"Log : .* \n"
```

Or specify what exactly You want to match and retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like so: `Log\s*:\s*([\d.]+)[\s-]+\[([\d\/A-Za-z: -]+)\]\s+"([A-Z]+)\s+(.+?)"\s+([\s\d]+)`.

This will match the following into groups:

1. 64.242.88.10
2. 07/Mar/2004:16:05:49 -0800
3. GET
4. /twiki/bin/edit/Main/Double_bounce_sender?topicparent=Main.ConfigurationVariables HTTP/1.1
5. 401 12846

An example is available [here](https://regex101.com/r/aW1aC6/1).